# How to fill a .word array with spaces? MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips

Currently attempting to fill this array with spaces to display blank points.

using lw to display the numbers and get large numbers

```
.data

array: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
spaces: .word SPACES
SPACES: .asciiz  " "

main:
jal spacefiller
jr $ra

SpaceFiller:
  lw $t3,spaces
  bge $t0,9,endloop
  sw $t3,0($t2)
  addi $t0,$t0,1
  addi $t2,$t2,4
  j SpaceFiller
```

Comment: You're using `$t2` as an address without having assigned it a value anywhere in your code. It's also not clear what you need `spaces` or `SPACES` for. You can just do `li $t3,' '`. Unless you actually want each element of `array` to contain _the address of_ a string consisting of a space character.

Comment: Why would you want to fill a word array with spaces?  Word arrays hold word-sized items: 4 bytes, aka 32-bit integer. A space is a byte-sized character.  Can you explain why you'd do this, or perhaps what you really are trying to do?